# Error in tq_get, x = 'MKL', get = 'stock.prices': Error in new.session(): Could not establish session after 5 attempts

Tags: r, quantmod, tidyquant

I am having difficulties pulling stock data. The code has worked earlier today, however this afternoon I became unable to pull any stock data at all. Is anyone else experiencing this error or have you figured out a solution.

Here is a selection of my code

```
library(here)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(furrr)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

plan(multisession, workers = 4)

# Set time frame

end <- "2021-12-31"
beg <- "2016-12-31"
risk_free_rate <- 0.02

# Import data ----

stock_sp <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = here("Stock_List_Port_2.xlsx")) %>%
  setNames(c("ticker", "sic"))

tickers <- sample(x = stock_sp$ticker, size = 1)
#tickers <- stock_sp$ticker


stock_data_full <- map(tickers, function(ticker){

  tidyquant::tq_get(x = ticker,
                    get = "stock.prices",
                    verbose = TRUE,
                    from = beg, to = end)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this morning and found this post a few hours later.

https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/358

The repository owner was notified of the issue and pushed a patch.